# Обратный отсчет времени в цикле

Tags: c#, время, счетчики, циклы

Приветствую.

Собственно, тема вопроса:

В форму нужно повесить пять лейблов, независимых друг от друга, которые будут считать по пол часа от заданного времени, обратный отсчет. Когда отсчет пройден, начинается новый получасовой отсчет. К примеру, в восемь утра стартует отсчет и каждые пол часа он обновляется, и к примеру, меняет цвет.

Я понял, что нужно делать BGWorkerы и таймеры, только что-то не могу свои понятия применить на практике, как сделать цикл этих считалок. Если не затруднит, черканите пару строк, или ссылкой киньтесь.

Заранее благодарю

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Простое решение в лоб с помощью таймера:

```
private const int minutes = 30;
private const int seconds = 60;
private int remains = minutes * seconds ;

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var timer = (Timer) sender;
    remains = remains == 0 ? minutes * seconds  : remains - timer.Interval / 1000;
    yourLabel.Text = String.Format("{0:D2} : {1:D2}", remains / 60, remains % 60);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

А зачем таймер? Делаем статик класс, запоминаем время и каждый раз при загрузке страницы проверяем, прошло ли пол часа. Вводим еще переменную текущего и прошлого состояния (количество прошедших получасовых интервалов) и при смене их меняем цвет или что там надо.

Comment: и через пару дней аптайма сервант ляжет...

Comment: @SomeName: Какой загрузке страницы? Речь идёт о десктопном приложении.

@VaLenOK007: почему ляжет? Неужели 3 строки кода раз в полчаса — такая большая нагрузка?

Comment: @VaLenOK007
Ну, да, чтоб избежать переполнения стека, лучше в переменную состояния просто сохранять предыдущую дату. 
@VladD Ахтожйогознав, никаких намеков, что это именно декстоп нет.